# SqlDateTime overflow. When using Datetime as parameter in C# for SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

Part of a SQL project where multiple users are connected using different isolation levels. I created a method for my query. As in the code, I tried to send my method as 'year month day' but I got an error like this. Where is the problem?

The error is :

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Code:

```
public SqlCommand Update(DateTime beginDate, DateTime endDate, SqlTransaction transaction, SqlConnection conn)
{ 
    string updatequery = "UPDATE Sales.SalesOrderDetail"+
                         "SET UnitPrice = UnitPrice * 10.0 / 10.0"+
                         "WHERE UnitPrice > 100"+
                         "AND EXISTS (SELECT* FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader"+
                                     "WHERE Sales.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID = "+
                                "Sales.SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID"+
                                     "AND Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate"+
                                "BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate"+
                                "AND Sales.SalesOrderHeader.OnlineOrderFlag = 1)";

    SqlParameter BeginDateparam = new SqlParameter("@BeginDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    BeginDateparam.Value = beginDate;

    SqlParameter EndDateparam = new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    EndDateparam.Value = endDate;

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updatequery, conn, transaction);
    command.Parameters.Add(BeginDateparam);
    command.Parameters.Add(EndDateparam);

    return command;
}

public void TypeA()
{
    int exceptioncountA = 0;
    int otherExCountA = 0;

    SqlTransaction transaction = null;
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(isolationlevel);
            Random random = new Random();
            double randomnumber = random.NextDouble();

            if (randomnumber < 0.5)
                Update(new DateTime(20110101), new DateTime(20111231), transaction, conn).ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (randomnumber < 0.5)
                Update(new DateTime(20120101), new DateTime(20121231), transaction, conn).ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (randomnumber < 0.5)
                Update(new DateTime(20130101), new DateTime(20131231), transaction, conn).ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (randomnumber < 0.5)
                Update(new DateTime(20140101), new DateTime(20141231), transaction, conn).ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (randomnumber < 0.5)
                Update(new DateTime(20150101), new DateTime(20151231), transaction, conn).ExecuteNonQuery();

            transaction.Commit();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex1)
        {
            if (ex1.Number == 1205)
            {
                try
                {
                    ++exceptioncountA;
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception coun of TypeA .. {0}", exceptioncountA);
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
                catch(Exception ex2)
                {
                    ++otherExCountA;
                    Console.WriteLine("Rollback ederken hata oluştu {0}  Mesaj : {1}",ex2.GetType(),ex2.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception otherEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(otherEx.Message);
            ++otherExCountA;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }

    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
    var totalTimeTypeA = endTime - startTime;
    // writeToFile( totalTimeTypeA);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Examine

```
 new DateTime(20151231)
```

It's not the date you think it is.  You're calling [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int64_) constructor,

> Parameters ticks Int64 A date and time expressed in the number of
> 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at
> 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar.

Instead call

```
new DateTime(2015,12,31);
```

Comment: That part's fine.  You just need to fix the DateTime values.

Comment: In fact, `new DateTime(20151231)` represents January 1, 0001 at time 00:00:02.0151231, i.e. a bit more than two seconds after midnight on January 1, 0001, in the proleptic Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because the datetime your passing is not getting parsed and setting up as default date

`new DateTime(20120101);` => `1/1/0001 12:00:02 AM`  which is wrong

You need pass the proper datetime in the your `update()` method then it will work